# Google Appengine Datastore filter and sort direction together

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the below SQL query in datastore

```
     Select *from users where catagory="A" ODER BY id.
```

I tried the below code

```
         DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
  Filter filter=new FilterPredicate("catagory", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "A");


      Query q = new Query("users");  
      q.setFilter(filter);
      q.addSort("id", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
```

The `setfilter()` and `addsort()` functions are not working together. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do they work independently?

Comment: Yes it works independently

Comment: I even tried adding datastore-indexes.xml with .<datastore-index kind="user" ancestor="false" source="manual"> <property name="catagory" direction="asc"/> <property name="id" direction="desc"/> </datastore-index>

Comment: And what if you daisy-chain the query: `Query q = new Query("users").setFilter(filter).addSort("id", SortDirection.DESCENDING);`

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you getting an error?

Comment: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. recommended index is: - kind: users properties: - name: catagory - name: id direction: desc

Answer (score 0):

From [Class DatastoreNeedIndexException](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreNeedIndexException#class-datastoreneedindexexception):

> `DatastoreNeedIndexException` is thrown when no matching index was
>   found for a query requiring an index. Check the Indexes page in the
>   Admin Console and your datastore-indexes.xml file.

In many cases the development server creates the necessary indexes automatically when your app requires them. See [Creating indexes using the development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#creating_indexes_using_the_development_server).

But in some cases the automatic index updates don't happen. In such cases you need to create/update the indexes manually. See [Creating indexes manually](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#creating_indexes_manually).

Updating the indexes on GAE also happens most of the time automatically, when the app code is deployed, but occasionally they need to be updated manually. From [Updating indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#updating_indexes):

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update_indexes myapp/war
```

After the GAE indexes are updated it may take a while for them to get in `serving` state. Until that state is reached the same error can be seen. Check the [status of the app's indexes](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes) in the developer's console. Also mentioned in [Updating indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#updating_indexes).